# Ionic: Uninstalling app from device and reinstalling it again because the installed app already signed with different key

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm building 2 ionic projects on the same time, different directories of course.
Json & XML have different names, different versions of those 2 applications.

Normally i test my applications during development with `ionic cordova run android -l` and keep refreshing the app on save.

The problem is that when i change directory to work on the other project and run the same command, for some reason is uninstalls from my mobile the first application and installed the second one, even the applications are different.

Is that normal to happen or I can avoid it somehow ? 
The message says : `Uninstalling app from device and reinstalling it again because the installed app already signed with different key`.

What i want is to have both applications installed in my mobile.

Thank you.

Comment: If you did not use `-l`, does it happen?

Comment: I havent tried as it's out of my scope. I want to be able to do live reload while developing.

Comment: Ya, I just want to ensure the problem come from `-l`

Comment: Thank you I tried and it still happens.

Comment: Please post your config.xml of 2 projects

Comment: I'll post on monday - since i dont have physical access now. many thanks for trying to help @Duannx

Answer (score 0):

I found what it was, inside the config.xml you dont need to change only the app name but also the widget ID. in my case the widget id was default on both applications thats why the problem occurred. I post in case anyone else has the same problem.